# Woocommerce: Send Tracking Details to Paypal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I am using Shipment Tracking (https://woocommerce.com/products/shipment-tracking/) and offering Paypal standard as a payment option.

Recently we have been flagged by Paypal and they are now not releasing payments until we add tracking information to our orders. How do we do this?

I have tried looking for a plugin without much success, but figured it might be an API thing we can send?

Am at a bit of a loss to work out how to do this - any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: That should be handled by the shipment plugin. Ask them for support or use this to automate it - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/tracking/integrate/ .

Comment: I don't know how much of a difference it makes for tracking (perhaps none) but also check whether you're using the official PayPal for WooCommerce plugin (vs. one of the many other "standard" PayPal payment implementations that may vary in which features they support) https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-paypal-payments/ . As for the tracking API, anything it would accomplish can also be done manually in the www.paypal.com account interface after order fulfillment/shipment